# C programming, fprintf() not working correctly

Tags: c

Probably a silly mistake I am doing here.

```
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("test.txt", "a+");
    fprintf(fp, time_stamp(),"FLAG 1, Timestamp : %s\n");
    fclose(fp);
```

I am getting timestamp from a function
But The file writing only timestamp, not the flag
If I remove timestamp, FLAG 1 printing. But Not getting together. ie

```
Flag 1, Timestamp : 20141005141116
```

The output I am getting in test.txt like

```
20141005145640201410051456402014100514564020141005145640201410051456412014100514564120141
```

Not going to new line and print like:

```
Flag 1, Timestamp : 20141005141116
Flag 1, Timestamp : 20141005141117
Flag 1, Timestamp : 20141005141118
```

.....
like that

Please solve this issue

Comment: Please compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). You would get a warning from the compiler, if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...

Comment: where is printf used?

Comment: @Zaibis: OP probably think of `fprintf`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have the arguments to `fprintf()` in the wrong order. Look at the [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fprintf)'s prototype:

```
int fprintf(FILE *stream, const char *format, ...);
```

Clearly, the formatting string comes *before* the things being formatted (the variable part `...`).

Assuming `time_stamp()` returns a static string, your code should be:

```
fprintf(fp, "FLAG 1, Timestamp : %s\n", time_stamp());
```

Comment: fprintf("FLAG 1, Timestamp : %s\n",fp,timestamp());
Is that? actually doing c after a long time hence...basic problems

Comment: @anupam_on Uh no? Please *look* at the prototype, or the code I gave you in the answer above. First the file pointer, then the formatting string, then the things being formatted.

Comment: +1. This is possibly the nicest answer I have ever seen. Concise, to the point and all the relevant links.

Comment: @Joshpbarron Gee, thanks! I try, and in this regard I think practice really helps. :)

Comment: Joshpbarron ya, correctly said, very rare type of answering. But yes, some people are there to do things precisely, to the point and correctly :)
Thanks buddy @unwind Problem solved :)

Answer (score 3):

Arguments to [`fprintf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fprintf) should be like this :

```
fprintf(fp, "FLAG 1, Timestamp : %s\n", time_stamp());
```